# Maven Test does not open Chrome browser with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven-3

I have created a Maven Project with TestNG for selenium webdriver (Chrome Browser). I run a basic test with TestNG and Chrome browser is successfully opened. Buf if I run the same test with "Maven Test" command and I get an error message.

Could you please help? I have tried many solutions like suggested by Stack Overflow but still unsuccessful :(

- I run "Maven Test" for a basic test "Hello World" and the build is successful >>> Evidence that "Maven Test" creates a successful build
- I run TestNG test with the command to open Chrome Browser and it works >>> evidence that TestNG works successfully
- I run "Maven Test" with the command to open Chrome Browser and it does NOT work >>> getting frustrated with this, tried all solutions appeared in StackOverflow but unsuccesful
- I have created testng.xml file
- I have used different versions for Selenium-Java and Selenium-Server dependencies as well as for Chromedriver and SureFire plugin but the problem is still there, now I am using the latest for all of them (see POM file below for more details).
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled Google Chrome and now I have latest version 73
- I have no firewall on my machine

POM file appears below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MavenProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

testng.xml file appears below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="MavenPackage.NewTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
```

My code is below:

```
public class NewTest {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void MyFunction() {
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.get("http://www.ebay.com");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.quit();
            System.out.println("Test passed");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error message

```
Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 49053
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 23.798 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
[ERROR] MyFunction(MavenPackage.NewTest)  Time elapsed: 21.874 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-DV883K3', ip: '192.168.1.109', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at MavenPackage.NewTest.MyFunction(NewTest.java:20)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:49053/status] to be available after 20008 ms
at MavenPackage.NewTest.MyFunction(NewTest.java:20)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at MavenPackage.NewTest.MyFunction(NewTest.java:20)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   NewTest.MyFunction:20 » WebDriver Timed out waiting for driver server to start...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 28.467 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-30T23:32:42Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) on project MavenProject: There are test failures.
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
```

This indicates that ChromeDriver is unable to initiate new chrome browser session.

Please update your java to latest version (as per message we can see the you are running java.version: '1.8.0_201' which is older,consider updating to latest java version 11.0)

The possible reasons:

- older chrome driver (consider update to the latest chromedriver https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=73.0.3683.68/)
- Chrome browser version mismatch (check the browser version and chromedriver compatibility at https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection)

Consider executing a single `@Test` directly to make sure the environment is good, then use the `testng.xml` for further executions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have latest versions for both Chromedriver and Google Chrome browser (both versions 73). I'll try updating the jdk from version 8 to version 11 but I don't think this is the main issue. Happy to be proved wrong of course. Also, run code as "TestNG" 
and browser starts fine while run as "Maven Test" the browser is not launched. It doesn't make much sense to me :(

Comment: Hmm. Little weird, will check with maven and see.

Comment: Don't see any issue with the same setup what you have, except I have latest Java version.

Comment: Thanks again Supputuri. I'll try with Java 11 and let you know the outcome.